# I have a table with city and population. I want to run a random based in population

Tags: mysql, random

I have a city table with: "name" and "population".
I want to select randomly a city, but based in the population.

New York - 19.000.000
City 2 - 1.000.000

So randomly I have 19X more chance to get "New York" than "City 2".

Of course this table has much more cities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ed King answer didnt work for me.  I dont know why.

Mathematically looks, great.

But I inserted 300k random cities in a table. About 90% got the city with most population. 
And this city just represent 5% of total country population. So I got a really strange result.

Maybe mysql is caching RAND() or something.. I dont know.

I made by myself this sql above, and my test was pretty right.

```
   SELECT @som := 0, @sorted := FLOOR( RAND()*(SELECT SUM(population) FROM cities ) );

   SELECT ord.id, ord.initial, ord.final FROM
        (
           SELECT 
               id, @som+1 AS initial, @som := @som + population  AS final 
           FROM cities
        ) ord
   HAVING @sorted
   BETWEEN 
       ord.initial AND ord.final;
```

Comment: My answer will sort them randomly based on population, if you always take the first, you will most likely always get the city with the largest population -- it's unlikely that rand*3m is less than rand*50k, so the sort is random, but you're always picking the top.  using offset / limit will allow you to pick throughout the list.

Answer (score 2):

To randomly select records weighted by population, this will work:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY (RAND() * population);
```

Adding LIMIT allows only one, randomly picked and weighted by population:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename ORDER BY (RAND() * population) LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: I see, pretty smart.. :)  bigger population will have "more chance" to get bigger random numbers..

Comment: But... Im thinking.. probably I need to use "DESC" right?